# Can someone explain this circuit to me? I'm especially confused about how the transistors work with their bases connected to each other

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, npn

[image]

This circuit is from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt7HHOXn1nk) video.
I'm confused about how the transistors work in this circuit.

Comment: What circuit is it and what does it do? There's just a transistor used as a diode which is in series with LED and resistor. And some seemingly unrelated circuit that does nothing.

Comment: If the pinout is ECB, the capacitive sensor (it's not an inductor, even if it looks like one) should be in the base of one transistor and the emitter of the other, right?

Comment: The circuit does not appear to do anything sensible = explanation. Hint - don't leave floating (and therefore ambiguous/inexplicable) nodes. Please also explain where the circuit came from i.e. paint a little context to your question.

Comment: @Andyaka the circuit works with the floating node. It's a ghost detector as clearly shown in the video. It's the schematic that is wrong.

Comment: @SredniVashtar hehe

Comment: That is not how the transistors are connected.

Comment: [C945 Transistor Pinout, Equivalent, Uses, Features & Applications](https://www.componentsinfo.com/c945-pinout-equivalent/)  ECB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bases aren't connected together.  Here is the circuit from the video:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsYTA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The coil of wire picks up induced voltage and feeds it to the base of Q1 which drives the base of Q2 which drives the LED.  You could probably calculate the precise length of the antenna wire to increase sensitivity for a specific frequency but since none of the parameters (conductor length, coil diameter, turn spacing) are given or apparently even measured in the video, my guess is that it's coiled just to save space and make it look more official.

I would not trust my life to this circuit.

Comment: +1 for producing the correct circuit, but that is not an antenna: it's half of a capacitor that couples with the conductors that carry current in the neighbour of the circuit.

Comment: I think the input of this circuit would be considered capacitive if Q1 were a MOSFET or IGBT (capacitive gate, would react to *voltage* or *charge*.)  But an NPN BJT has a diode-like gate and operates on *current flow*.  Er.go., a base won't store charge so is not capacitive.  (There are tiny parasitic capacitances of both devices which were ignored for this comment.)  The arrangement of Q1 and Q2 multiplies their amplification or "beta" - perhaps 5000x or so.  So very tiny currents into the "antenna" (nano-amps) can light the LED.

Comment: It does not need to store charge; the AC current flows into the base. I simulated a similar circuit using the coupling capacitances with an AC mains cylindrical conductor, following Ott's EMC textbook, and I got currents and voltages in the right ballpark. This is not an electrometer, it's an AC coupled circuit. (And it would be far more sensitive if LED and R were on the high side)  . And no, an antenna works on retardation, this is quasistatic at 50 Hz.